# How do I replace a file on Laravel's file system

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5

I have a form which accepts a resume, and I would like the user to be able to upload files. I got this route to work, however, I want to replace the files uploaded by that user (I rename the file with their last name and the current time). My code is below:

```
$file = $request->file('cv');
$fileName = $user->id . "+" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$destinationPath = config('app.CVDestinationPath') . "/" . $fileName . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
if ($uploaded) { //update the database
   dd("DONE"); 
}
```

So if a user has an `id` of 2, and he uploads two files. I will have two files associated with that user. I want to replace any file with the `id` of 2 if it exists. Also what is the max file size upon a post request I can store? 
Can anyone provide any guidance?

Comment: you can just use `$fileName = $user->id . ""`

Comment: You can just delete the old file and store new file over there and update your database accordingly.

Comment: @SagarGautam yea but how do I delete the old file? since I do not know the time it was uploaded?

Comment: Have you stored old uploaded file details ?

Comment: @SagarGautam nope :$, I was hoping if I had a substring of the file name (their lastName) I could delete that file. Also is it possible for me to change the max file upload size upon a post request?

Comment: You need details of uploaded file to track later.

Comment: @SagarGautam yea so I guess, I will use something else instead of current time, one which doesn't change. Could you help me configuring the max file size?